# Is it possible to pass a JQuery datepicker object via Laravel Controller into database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I've looked everywhere and really not so sure if this is possible.

I have an inline datepicker with an altField and I want the selected date to be inserted into the database. The $service_id, $service_name and $service_price are passed in.

I know I'm doing something wrong, hence why I would like to ask for some advice here.

Here's some of my show.blade.php contents

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            // showOtherMonths: true,
            // selectOtherMonths: true,
            // numberOfMonths: 2,
            firstDay: 1,
            altField: "#dateofbooking",
            altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: "+2W",
        });
    });


</script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-7 text-center">
        <div id="datepicker" class="text-center"></div>

    </div> <!-- col-sm-8 end -->
    <div class="col-sm-1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        {!! Form::open(['action' => 'PagesController@storebooking', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}

        <div class="form-group"></br>
            <h3 class="text-center">Selected Service</h3>
            <hr class="featurette-divider">
            <h4 class="float-left">{{$service_name}}</h4>
            <h4 class="float-right">£ {{$service_price}}</h4>
            <br>
            {{Form::hidden('service_id', $service_id, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Service ID'])}}
            {{Form::hidden('service_name', $service_name, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Service Name'])}}
            {{Form::hidden('service_price', $service_price, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Service Price'])}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"></br>
            <h3>Selected Date:</h3>
<!-- This will be hidden -->
        {{Form::text('dateofbooking', '', ['id' => 'dateofbooking', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Booking Date'])}}
        </div>
            {{Form::submit('Book Appointment', ['class' => 'submitbtn btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block', 'style' => 'border-radius: 20px;'])}}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div> <!-- col-sm-4 end -->
</div> <!-- div row end -->
```

@endsection

What I'm using to store the information

```
 public function storebooking(Request $request)
{
    $services = new Service;
    $bookings = new Booking;
    $bookings->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $bookings->username = auth()->user()->username;
    $bookings->firstname = auth()->user()->firstname;
    $bookings->surname = auth()->user()->surname;
    $bookings->email = auth()->user()->email;


    $bookings->service_id = $request->input('service_id');
    $bookings->service_name = $request->input('service_name');
    $bookings->service_price = $request->input('service_price');
    // $booking->dateofbooking = $request->input('dateofbooking'); // Doesn't work

    $bookings->save();
    return redirect('history')->with('success', 'Appointment Booked');
}
```

Comment: what do you get when you dd($request->all())

Comment: If I put it before $booking->dateofbooking = $request->input('alt_field'); then the passed in variables: array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "WC6thJdFmDzRp2E3lBUw16i8YK466K3RzJrz4CIg"
  "service_id" => "28"
  "service_name" => "Children's Trim"
  "service_price" => "12.00"
] If I put it after $booking->dateofbooking = $request->input('alt_field'); then I get the  "Creating default object from empty value" error message

Comment: ignore what I said before, use $request->input('dateofbooking'); and keep your form as it was previously. 
Then do the dd($request->all()), see if the value is being passed

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! :) Used the {{Form::text('dateofbooking', '', ['id' => 'dateofbooking'])}} in the form and $bookings->dateofbooking = $request->input('dateofbooking'); and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [MGS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7313939/mgs) for helping me troubleshoot and come up with the solution.

For anyone else having any problems, this solved my issue:

show.blade.php

```
{{Form::hidden('dateofbooking', '', ['id' => 'dateofbooking'])}}
```

and used this in function storebooking

```
$bookings->dateofbooking = $request->input('dateofbooking');
```